# How to unscope query, but keep has_many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

How can I "unscope" queries but keeping `has_many` relations?

I have two models. Each of them has `default_scopes`, and I query with different `scopes` too (`visibility`, `active`, etc.. )

```rb
class Shop
    has_many :products
    scope :active, -> { where(active: true, visible: true) }
end

class Product
  belongs_to :shop
  default_scope { where(:visible => true, active: true) }
end

active_shop = Shop.create(name: "active",
                          active: true, 
                          visible: true)

inactive_shop = Shop.create(name: "inactive",
                            active: false,
                            visible: false)

active_shop.products.create!(name "active product", 
                            visible: true,
                            active: true)

inactive_shop.products.create!(name "inactive product", 
                              visible: false,
                              active: false)
```

Sometimes I need to change values for all related products of a specific shop.
I have to "unscope" the products to overcome the `default_scope`:
But I have then the problem, that this also removes the `has_many` query:

```rb
inactive_shop.products.unscoped.map(&:name)
# ["inactive product","active product"]
```

But I expect only to return the `"inactive product"`

Hint: This is a simplified example. So a simple

```rb
  scope :visible, -> { where(visible: true) }
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
```

is not possible, because the scopes are more complex in my real code.

What I need is a something like this: `Shop.products.all_products_of_this_shop_equally_which_scope`

With `unscoped` I also get ALL Products of the whole App. `Unscope` also adds the `Products` of the other `Shop`:

```rb
>> Shop.last.products.to_sql
   Shop Load (1.9ms)  
     SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" 
     ORDER BY "shops"."id" 
     DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]

=> "SELECT \"products\".* FROM \"products\"
    WHERE \"products\".\"visible\" = TRUE 
    AND \"products\".\"active\" = TRUE 
    AND \"products\".\"shop_id\" = 234"

>> Shop.last.products.unscoped.to_sql
   Shop Load (2.7ms)  
     SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops"
     ORDER BY "shops"."id" 
     DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]

=> "SELECT \"products\".* FROM \"products\""

# BUT I NEED THIS: 

"SELECT \"products\".* FROM \"products\" 
 WHERE \"products\".\"shop_id\" = 234"
```

In the Product query I need to keep the relation to the shop, but wipe out all other queries

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try using `unscope` instead of `unscoped`. It allows specifying particular methods that need to be unscoped ([ref](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/unscope)), like this:

```
inactive_shop.products.unscope(where: %i[active visible]).map(&:name)
```

Or if there are many WHERE conditions in the default scope and you want to unscope all WHERE conditions except shop_id you can try something like this:

```
inactive_shop.products.unscope(
  where: inactive_shop.products.where_values_hash.except('shop_id').keys
).map(&:name)
```

At this point however I would instead think of getting rid of the default scope...

Comment: Thank you, is this also possible in the opposite way? Unscope everything "except" the relation? something like `products.unscope_except(where: :shop)` As I wrote, my query is a bit more complex, and it could get a bit unclear/confusing. OR SHOULD I simply pack that code into a `scope` ?

Comment: I've added a second code block in the answer. It's not exactly what you are asking but it's close I think. If it's something even more complicated than a bunch of different where conditions in the default_scope maybe it's best to get rid of the default_scope itself because it's getting far too complicated to get around.

Comment: I got the point. Thank you Dmytro. I find it interesting, that there is no "clean rails way" to do this. I stick with your first example and added all in a new scope: `scope :everything, -> {unscope(where: %i[active visible])}`. So I can do `shop.products.everything` and do something with it.

Comment: No problem.
My personal understanding is that many Rails developers try to avoid default_scopes so probably that's why there is no clean way. It's also now a bit misleading semantically, compare your `shop.products.everything` with `shop.products.all`. Sounds about the same yet the results are very different.

Comment: With `all` only `default_scope` results are available. I use `default_scope` to avoid accidently show results which should be hidden. But with `everything` I've the option to show "really" `all` with the `has_many` scope still activated